# Javascript Accordion Section dissapears on pressing backspace

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript Accordian with 3 sections. However when the default populated content of the bottom two section is deleted and if you press backspace after that, then the whole section dissapears. Interesting this only happens with 2 sections, the top one does not behave the same way. It stay even when content is deleted and backspace is pressed. Clueless on why that is. I tried playing around with css but haven figured out yet.

Comment: Could you attachment the code?

Comment: do you have any code?

Comment: Code is part of a larger project, so thats pretty complex. But here is a part of the css that accordian uses

Comment: `&__right {
  width: calc(40vw - 32px);
  max-width: 600px;
  min-width: 500px;
  padding: 24px;
  border:none;
  collapse: false;

  &__accordion-header {
   display: flex;
   flex-grow: 1;
   & .toggle {
    margin-left: 20px;
   }
  }

  &__accordion-body {
   padding: 0 18px;
  collapse: false;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

  }`

Comment: Cant seem to figure out the formatting

Comment: It's not going to be CSS that causes this behavior.  We're going to need HTML and javascript here too.  Please edit your question to add the requested code (not put in a comment).